# How to get all the comments of a particular organisation in github?

Tags: github, github-api

There is an organisation on github and I need to get all the comments from all the pull requests that are there. Can you please tell me how to do this?

I've tried going through each pull request and getting comments that way, it works, but I think it could be done somehow more optimally

Answer (score 0):

You should see this here, I don't know how big your organization is or how many repositories you have either for an organization or in a personal account.

Anyway, I don't see how to do this any other way than using the Github API, and in this case I'm in doubt if the REST API can be used for this.

But I'm sure GraphQL API can help you with that, check out these links about GitHub GraphQL API and its explorer to see what you get.

- https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer
- https://docs.github.com/en/rest?apiVersion=2022-11-28
- https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference
- https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/forming-calls-with-graphql

Hope this helps.